# Z-Indexed drop down menu not diplaying above a following div ul

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, z-index, visible

I have added a second row on my menu_Box called menu_Box2

Trying my shot at Z-Indexing for the first time.

I cannot to get the menu_Box drop down menu to appear above menu_Box2 items.

Ive tried some different z-Index, overflow and position values with no luck.

I think I may need to Z-index some of the ul li items, but since they are group together its difficult for me to figure out which ones.

CSS:

```
#menu_Box{   /*MENU BOX CONTAINER*/
width: 890px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left: 10px;

z-index:500

}

#menu_Box2{   /*MENU BOX CONTAINER*/
width: 890px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top:6px;

overflow:visible;

}
#menu_Box ul,
#menu_Box2 ul{ /*MENU BOX STYLE*/
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:rgba(0, 57, 96, .95); 
font-size:24px; 
font-weight:normal;
padding:0 0 0 8px;
margin:0;
position:relative;
}
.extraStyle{
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:rgba(0, 57, 96, .85); 
font-size:22px;
font-weight:normal;
padding:0 0 0 7px;
margin:0;
}
#menu_Box ul li,
#menu_Box2 ul li{
 display:inline-block;
}
#menu_Box ul li:hover,
#menu_Box ul li a:hover,
#menu_Box2 ul li:hover,
#menu_Box2 ul li a:hover{
 color:#456692;
 text-decoration:none;

}
#menu_Box ul li a,visited,
#menu_Box2 ul li a,visited{
 text-align:left;
 color:#263A75; 
 display:block;
 padding: 0 0 0 0; /*Padding between titles*/ 
 text-decoration:none;
}
#menu_Box ul li:hover ul,
#menu_Box ul ul li,
#menu_Box2 ul li:hover ul,
#menu_Box2 ul ul li{
 display:block; 
}
#menu_Box ul ul,
#menu_Box2 ul ul{ /*Drop Down Box*/
border: 3px solid rgba(0, 57, 96, .85) ;
display:none;
position:absolute;
background-color: rgba(139, 183, 212, .9);
padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px; /*Padding between list items*/    
}
#menu_Box ul ul li a,visited,
#menu_Box2 ul ul li a,visited{
color:#263A75;  
}
#menu_Box ul ul li a:hover,
#menu_Box2 ul ul li a:hover{
color:#456692;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu_Box">     <!--Menu Box Div-->
<ul>

<li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/index.php">Services</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/index.php#headerH2pk">Psych-K</a> </li>
       <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/index.php#headerH2fat">Food & Environmental Allergy and Sensitivity Testing</a> </li>
       <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/index.php#headerH2sne">Supplement and Nutrition Evaluation</a> </li>
       <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/index.php#headerH2fvt">Food Value Testing</a> </li>
    </ul> 
</li><span class="extraStyle">::</span>

<li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/sessions.php">Sessions</a> </li><span class="extraStyle">::</span>

<li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/bio.php">Biography</a> </li><span class="extraStyle">::</span>

<li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/forums.php">Health Topics</a>
   <!-- <ul>
       <li><a href="http://open-source-energy.org/forum/index.php">Open Source Forums</a> </li>
       <li><a href="http://open-source-energy.org/forum/index.php">Open Source Forums</a> </li>
   </ul>-->
</li><span class="extraStyle">::</span>

<li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/products.php">Favorite Products</a></li><span class="extraStyle">::</span>

<li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca/contact.php">Contact</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>     <!--Close Menu Box Div-->





<div id="menu_Box2">     <!--Menu Box Div-->
<ul>   
  <li><a href="http://www.enhancedliving.ca">Recipies</a>
</ul>
</div>     <!--Close Menu Box Div-->
```

Comment: Ok great guys. I added  z-index:1;  to menu_Box ul and it work. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The `z-index` property only applies to positioned elements, so add `position: relative;` to your `#menu_Box`

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index:500` to `menu_Box ul` not `menuBox` (I would use **z-index 1**, not **z-index 500** because it is just enough to go above `menu_Box2`)

**CSS:**

```
#menu_Box ul
{
    z-index:1;
}
```

This works because you need to add it to the 'popup-box', not the text.
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XyLhS/)**